# Load data on startup

Tags: python, django

I have a file with a bunch of data common between several projects. The data needs to be loaded into the Django database. The file doesn't change that much, so loading it once on server start is sufficient. Since the file is shared between multiple projects, I do not have full control over the format, so I cannot convert this into a fixture or something.

I tried loading it in ready(), but then I run into a problem when creating a new database or migrating an existing database, since apparently ready() is called before migrations are complete and I get errors from using models that do not have underlying tables. I tried to set it in class_prepared signal handler, but the loading process uses more than one model, so I cannot really be sure all required model classes are prepared. Also it seems that ready() is not called when running tests, so unit tests fail because the data is missing. What is the right place to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what I am looking for doesn't exist. Django trusts the user to deal with migrations and such and doesn't check the database on load. So there is no place in the system where you can load some data on system start and be sure that you can actually load it. What I ended up doing is loading the data in ready(), but do a sanity check first by doing MyModel.objects.exist() in a try: except: block and returning if there was an exception. This is not ideal, but I haven't found any other way.